# Lucene and EntityGraphs

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lucene

I recently started using Lucene in combination with Hibernate and JPA and wondered how to load lazy relations.
I am used to using JPAs EntityGraphs but I couldn't find anything in their documentation about lazy collections.

So what is the best way to handle loading lazy collections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is a [high-performance, full-featured text search engine](https://lucene.apache.org/core/), not a JPA provider. The concept of LAZY collections doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Map your entities to the Lucene index using [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/).

When you'll make any CRUD operation on the RDBMS via Hibernate ORM, it will keep the Lucene index in synch.

More importantly, it gives you an API to run Lucene Queries with all the benefits of Lucene, but return *managed entities* loaded from the RDBMS via Hibernate ORM.

This has several benefits:

- the entity will have lazy collections
- loaded within the same transaction
- easier to process than a Lucene query hit
- you express the Query using Lucene APIs (no loss in flexibility)
- the Query is also a JPA Query so it can be treated as such (easy pagination, framework integration)
- ...